# MaterialDesign- Flipper WPF: Alignment & Scalling is skew.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using the [Material Design](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) in a WPF XAML application, I've got this section of code bellow, when the grid is outside of a "materialDesign:Flipper" it all renders correctly; ie- it grows/stretch's correctly with the size of the window and it stacks nicely inside of the StackPanel.

However, as soon as I place this code inside of a Flipper, the scaling and positioning becomes skewed. If I start to change the size of the window it will resize funnily and will not stack nicely. Please see both the image and video bellow for more info. Thank you.

Please note all this code is contained within side a "StackPanel", the intention is such that they can be copied and pasted multiple times.

**Working Code outside a Flipper:**

```
<Grid Height="89">
    <Grid Width="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,3,0,2"  Panel.ZIndex="2" Height="84">
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Colour}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="#FF464646" Width="77" Effect="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignShadowDepth2}"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="90" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
    <UniformGrid  Rows="2" Columns="1" Panel.ZIndex="3" Margin="89,18,72,0">
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding BrandName}"  FontSize="24" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
        <Label Content="Brand Name" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="-2,-3,2,3"/>
     </UniformGrid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniDarkButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Panel.ZIndex="4" Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon DotsHorizontal}" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}" Margin="0,25,19,24"/>
    <materialDesign:Card  Margin="24,0,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="72" Panel.ZIndex="-1" />
</Grid>
```

**Broken Code, inside a Flipper:**

```
 <materialDesign:Flipper Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Background="#FFE89595" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <materialDesign:Flipper.FrontContent>
        Grid Height="89">
            <Grid Width="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,3,0,2"  Panel.ZIndex="2" Height="84">
                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Colour}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="#FF464646" Width="77" Effect="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignShadowDepth2}"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="90" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Foreground="White" />
            </Grid>
            <UniformGrid  Rows="2" Columns="1" Panel.ZIndex="3" Margin="89,18,72,0">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding BrandName}"  FontSize="24" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
                <Label Content="Brand Name" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="-2,-3,2,3"/>
             </UniformGrid>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniDarkButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Panel.ZIndex="4" Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon DotsHorizontal}" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}" Margin="0,25,19,24"/>
            <materialDesign:Card  Margin="24,0,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="72" Panel.ZIndex="-1" />
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:Flipper.FrontContent>
    <materialDesign:Flipper.BackContent>
        <Grid Height="200" Background="{Binding BackColour}">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniDarkButton}" Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon DotsHorizontal}" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:Flipper.BackContent>
</materialDesign:Flipper>
```

[Example Image of render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVSnT.png)

[YouTube Video Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p2-W6jHvdo)  - The one highlighted in red is flipper.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have the same issue. If you look at the XamlMaterialDesign demo project, the same lower quality rendering appears. It seems to be intrinsic with the Flipper control (as of jan 2019 at least). I found no workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to your flipper:

```
 Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCardFlipper}"
```

if you get (MaterialDesignCardFlipper not found) add the following code at the top of the window containing the flipper:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Flipper.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```